# Unit group of power series ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, power-series

Is there any way to calculate the multiplicative group of the units of power series ring $k[[x]]$, where $k$ is a field ?

Comment: The units in $k[[x]]$ are precisely those power series whose constant term is a unit. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** $\rm\displaystyle\quad 1\: =\: (a-xf)(b-xg)\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c00}{ab=\bf 1}\ $ so scaling top & bottom below by $\rm \,b\,$ yields
$$\Rightarrow\ \ \displaystyle\rm\ \ \frac{1}{a-xf}\ =\ \frac{b}{\color{#c00}{\bf 1}-bxf}\ =\ b\:(1+bxf+(bxf)^2+(bxf)^3+\:\cdots\:)$$

Comment: I still cannot see what to do next? how do you prove that the group of units are indeed power series with no-zero constant term?

Answer (score 2):

$\bf Hint:$ $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ is a unit iff $a_0\ne 0$.

Comment: Thank you azarel, this makes sense.

Comment: Could you give a hint as to why this is true?

Answer (score 2):

The multiplicative group is $k[[x]]\backslash (x)$.
Certainly those elements divisible by $x$ are not units. If an element is not divisble by $x$ (in other words, has nonzero constant term), you can construct the inverse term by term.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to be much more specific about the structure of the unit group than has been done so far, as follows. So far we know that the units in $k[[x]]$ are those formal power series with nonzero constant term. Dividing by the constant term shows that this group is isomorphic to $k^{\times}$ (the constant term part) times the group of formal power series $1 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \dots$ with constant term $1$.

> **Claim:** If $k$ has characteristic $0$, then this group is isomorphic to $(k[[x]], +)$. In particular, it is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

(Note that this can't be true in characteristic $p$ since the group of units is not $p$-torsion: we have, for example, $(1 + x)^p = 1 + x^p \neq 1$.)

The isomorphism is given by the "exponential" map

$$k[[x]] \ni f \mapsto (1 + x)^f \in k[[x]]^{\times}.$$

This is defined using the identity

$$1 + x = \exp \log (1 + x) = \exp \sum_{n \ge 1} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^n}{n}$$

(which is where we need that $k$ has characteristic $0$), which allows us to define

$$(1 + x)^f = \exp f \log (1 + x)$$

as a formal power series. This has all of the standard properties of the exponential, and is in particular a homomorphism. The inverse of this isomorphism is the "logarithm" map

$$\log_{1 + x}(g) = \frac{\log g}{\log (1 + x)}$$

where $g$ has constant term $1$. It's formal to verify that these two operations are inverse to each other.

The answer is more interesting in positive characteristic: <s>we get the underlying abelian group of the ring of [Witt vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witt_vector) $W(k)$. For example, when $k = \mathbb{F}_p$ this group is related to the group of $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and in fact there is a natural exponential $(1 + x)^f \in \mathbb{F}_p[[x]]$ where $f \in \mathbb{Z}_p$.</s> **Edit:** See the comments!

Comment: I think the unit group of $\mathbb F_p[[X]]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_p^\times\oplus\mathbb Z_p^{(\mathbb N)}$, where $\mathbb Z_p^{(\mathbb N)}$ denotes a countable direct sum of copies of the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: Just passing through and I noticed this answer. I think that Qiaochu's comment about the char p setting is inaccurate -- if $k=\mathbb{F}_p$ then the group is much much bigger than $\mathbb{Z}_p$ -- for example $(1+Xk[[X]]) / (1+X^Nk[[X]])$ is a finite $p$-group which is very far from being cyclic in general, and this sort of argument even shows that $1+Xk[[X]]$ is not finitely-generated. But I don't think @user26857's suggestion is right either -- as $1+Xk[[X]]$ is compact if $k$ is finite, whereas their suggestion does not seem to be (at least if I am interpreting it correctly).

Comment: I think that the unit group of $\mathbb{F}_p[[X]]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ direct sum a countably infinite product (not sum) of $\mathbb{Z}_p$'s, but this comment box is too small for me to fit the proof in.

Comment: The structure of $\Bbb F_p[[X]]^{\times}$ is given in thm 4.4 [here](http://math.arizona.edu/~ura-reports/063/McMurdie.Christopher/Final.pdf).

Comment: @KevinBuzzard is quite right: the units of $\Bbb F_p[[x]]$ that are $\equiv1\pmod x$ are a direct product of $\Bbb Z_p$’s, the indexing set being the positive integers prime to $p$.

Comment: Does anyone know a reference for Kevin Buzzard's assertion that $\mathbb F_p[[x]]^\times\cong \mathbb F_p^\times\times\prod_{\mathbb N}\mathbb Z_p$? (The source indicated by Watson is no longer accessible.)

Comment: @PeterKropholler: https://web.archive.org/web/20220526205303/https://www.math.arizona.edu/~ura-reports/063/McMurdie.Christopher/Final.pdf